# Image not displayed in a HTML5 wireframe

Tags: css, html

I don't understand why the image is not displayed with this code:

#### HTML:

```
<aside>
    <img />
<h3>Feature headline</h3>
</aside>
```

#### CSS:

```
aside {
        width: 286px;
        height: 200px;
        float: left;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: 20px;
        background: rgb(225,225,225);
    }
aside img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
        background: rgb(200,200,200);
    }
```

#### [JSFIDDLDE](http://jsfiddle.net/XWA45/)

while it is displayed with this other:

#### HTML:

```
    <div class="sharecontent">

        <h2>Organize headline</h2>

        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>

    </div>  

    <img>
```

#### CSS:

```
img {
        width: 440px;
        height: 225px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background: rgb(200,200,200);
    }
    .sharecontent {
        float:left;
        margin-left: 20px;
        width: 440px;
    }
```

#### [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9MQwJ/)

Any idea of why the image is not displayed in the first option?

Comment: Your first fiddle seems to work fine when there's an actual image with a `src` url present: http://jsfiddle.net/XWA45/1/

Comment: I see no image in either?

Comment: does <img> not need al least a src, even when it is empty?, just like a <a> needs a href, even when this is empty. BTW, i see a gray box in both examples

Comment: @Mark - If you look at the second option, it has no `scr` attribute and it is displayed.

Comment: I can see a gray block on both fiddles, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @xec - In the first option, it is the `aside` tag. Look at it with Firebug or other inspector.

Comment: I can see the image inside the aside... i.e. this is the same demo, only red img instead of gray: http://jsfiddle.net/XWA45/11/

Comment: @xec - I don't see any red block in your fiddle.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas You are missing the **obligatory** `src` attribute, which is why it's failing in Firefox (other browsers are fine)

Comment: Sidenote: I've had good times using http://imsky.github.io/holder/ for HTML wireframing.

Comment: @xec - It is just a wireframe, and the `src` is not needed (theoretically).

Comment: But you have just proved yourself wrong, firefox will have an issue with it, and the HTML is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly a Firefox issue. Works in all browsers but Firefox. Setting the `<img>` to `display: block` as suggested by Will solves the problem:

[image: Firefox issue]

**EDIT**: looks like it's the missing `src` attribute in the `img`. Though setting the element to `display: block` works, that might not be the correct solution. Then why use an `<img>`-tag.

Answer (score 2):

In your second example, adding `float: left;` creates a block. You need to set the img to `display: block;` to your first example.

EDIT: I'm apparently wrong on both points but http://jsfiddle.net/XWA45/3/ works (only added `display: block;`) and http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing#Some_boring_theory indicates that adding the float property creates a 'CSS Block'. I must be missing something.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XWA45/8/ is exactly the same as your demo, without the `display: block;` -- and works exactly the same.

Comment: You mean, except the part where you can't see the image? The image color should be teal. `background: rgb(0,200,200);`

Comment: It shows as teal for me, what browser are you using?

Comment: Just about to mention that. I just tested in Chrome and it *doesn't* need the `display: block;`. Firefox, the browser I'm using, does.

Comment: Aha! You are correct, firefox does not like the lack of a `src` attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/XWA45/13/ works in all browsers (note that there is no `display: block;` still)

Comment: Indeed, but since the OP mentioned wireframing and neither of the examples have one I'm guessing they don't want to add a src attribute. In which case, in order for it work in all browsers anyway, it needs `display: block`.

Comment: I upvoted this. You we're clearly right about the `display` (or missing src attr)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **obligatory** `src` attribute, which is why it's failing in Firefox (other browsers are fine)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img

> **src**
>
> > Image URL, this attribute is obligatory for the  element.

You can use lorempixel.com for testing layouts

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GwK75/